# Displaying unpublished Manuscripts correctly with apacite

Tags: apa-style, apacite

The correct way to cite an unpublished manuscript in apa is:
Author. (Year). *Title*. [Unpublished manuscript] Department of blabla, University of blabla.

However I can't get `LaTeX` to show me the "Department of blabla, University of blabla" part. Notes give parentheses such that: (Department of blabla, University of blabla)

Comment: Welcome. // Please post your minimal code, which compiles. Thank you